# Get value from DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a `DataGridView` called `ListingGrid` trying to activate / deactivate users that have been "checked" on any `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` that is inside the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.

This is the way im trying to do that :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow roow in ListingGrid.Rows)
{
    if ((bool)roow.Cells[0].Value == true)
    {
        if (ListingGrid[3, roow.Index].Value.ToString() == "True")
        {
            aStudent = new Student();
            aStudent.UserName = ListingGrid.Rows[roow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            aStudent.State = true;
            studentList.Add(aStudent);

        }
    }
}
```

As far as I get, when you check a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, the value of the cell is `true` right? But it is not allowing me to convert the value to bool and then compare it, throwing me an invalid cast exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563190/how-to-verify-if-a-datagridviewcheckboxcell-is-checked

Comment: Perhaps not entirely related to this question, but this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465766/5750078

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkchecking = roow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkchecking.Value) == true)
{
}
```

or

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkchecking = roow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if ((bool)chkchecking.Value == true)
    {
    }
```

Comment: the " as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;" worked marvellous, thank you!

Comment: There is no need to cast to a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell even though it works. You can simply do "Convert.ToBoolean(roow.Cells[0].Value);"

Comment: The first solution worked for me, the second one didn't. What could be the problem? Just curious.

Comment: This only works for me if I add the lines`code`  var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender; `code` senderGrid.EndEdit(); before checking the value (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563190/how-to-verify-if-a-datagridviewcheckboxcell-is-checked))

Answer (score 1):

Tried different options, same code sometimes worked and some other times it did not. Upon extensive debugging, it turned out that the root cause is not with the checkbox fetching code but the datagridvew mechanism itself.

The value of checkbox in the **active/selected** row was never received properly. If the datagridview has only one row, this issue can not be detected.

```
myDataGridViewName.EndEdit();
```

This has to be called before reading the cell values. After that the simple statements in the approved answer were enough.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(chkchecking.Value)
```

or

```
(bool)chkchecking.Value
```

both worked fine as expected. The credit for this tip goes to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901329/309856) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I think `== true` is not useful and you have to check if your cell is not [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
if (chkchecking.Value != DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it usually like this 
      `bool value =  (short)chkchecking.Value == 1`