# How retrieve the datagridview checkbox values

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In my project am I using datagridviewcheckbox , I can save this datagridviewcheckbox value in database, Here I want to retrieve the checkbox value in the same datagridviewcheckbox . How Can I do this. For windows application.

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean datagridviewcheckbox has `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632536/get-value-from-datagridviewcheckboxcell

Comment: Thank You for your reply.   I am using datagridviewcheckboxcolumn