# How to get datagridviewcheckboxcolumn value c#?

Tags: c#

In my window form application I have a datagridview which has a checkbox column I want to retrieve its value is checked or not I attempted

```
    if ((bool)dataGridView1[columnindex,rowindex].Value ==true )
{
   MessageBox.show ("checked");
 }
```

but it doesn't work 
please answer me

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13632536/302248

Answer (score 0):

This should works fine:

```
var value = dataGridView1[columnindex, rowindex].Value
```

So if you said "it doesn't work" - than just you need to provide us more information about error you got, etc.

Comment: it also doesn't work it says 'object reference not set to an instance of an object '

Comment: there is nothing more to say just I want to retrieve checkbox value  when it is checked by cellcontentclick event

Comment: Do you know how to debug? How do you get `columnindex` and `rowindex`?

Comment: e . rowindex and e . columnindex

Comment: any way I could find

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow roow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkchecking = roow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(chkchecking.Value) == true)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkbox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
bool ischecked = (bool)checkbox.EditedFormattedValue;
if (ischecked == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("True")
}
```

this code can get datagridview checkbox cell value