# Checking the value of a CheckBoxCell in a DataGridVIew C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have some records from a database displayed in a datagridview for the use to view and select data. I needed a way for users to select individual records for exporting the data into a formatted PDF document so I set up a CheckBoxCollumn. My Database and subsequent datagridviews are set up in tandem with one containing basic client information and the other the accounts associated with them. As I'm using the gridviews in tandem when a client is selected on the associate records show in the gridview. This means that if the user wants more than one clients records selected than they're unable to. To solve this problem I want to log what records have been checked and then when the PDF is generated it pulls the data from the records. My problem is with identifying which records are checked.

```
private void Accounts_DataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in accounts_DataGridView.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

            if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("its checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that I currently have. The event handling functions correctly but the value always returns null.

[My DataGridView for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXZpI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value from DataGridViewCheckBoxCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632536/get-value-from-datagridviewcheckboxcell)

Comment: @RatzMouze Gets me started. Its checking something but will only reads true when two checkboxes are checked. I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: That is because you do this every time you click on a cell, and then goes through all rows. You should only do this once, like on the ExportButton_Click event.

Comment: @RatzMouze I would like to do this but am unable to because each time I change the client of whose accounts I'm looking at the state of the checkbox is lost. I need to log the change when it happens so the use can select multiple accounts of multiple different clients.

Comment: That sounds like its going to be a very confusing UI. May i suggest that you do as i say, but instead of it being an "Export" button, its a "Too Export" button, that then puts all the checked records in a "cart"(like the one from an online shopping site), that is visualized somehow, so the user can see what is sent to export instead of remembering?
Then when the "Export" button is pressed, it will take the records from the "cart" and export them.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in the past and I never got it working with the `TrueValue` property.

Instead, I used the `cell.Value` property like below and I was able to continue my project without diving into the events of `DataGridView` that may be happening in the background.

```
if (cell.Value != null)
{
    string s = cell.Value.ToString();
    if (s == "True")
    {
       MessageBox.Show("its checked");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you convert the bool value to string if you are only going to use it for an if statement? What benefit do you get?

Comment: that is correct comment.No need to convert.Converting it to string back then helped me understand that a checkbox never checked =null and a checkbox thats is checked and then unchecked =false which is obviously the same result when you check the if its checked. The correct i suppose is : if (cell.value!=null && cell.value==true)

Answer (score 0):

If the DataGridView.DataSource is a `DataTable` (and you have the primary key for each row), after populating the DataTable, Add a column for permitting checking rows.

Here `table` is the DataTable

```cs
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "Process",
    DataType = typeof(bool),
    // important else default value is null
    DefaultValue = false 
});
```

In the DataGridView designer, set the column for the above `DataPropertyName` to `Process`. Otherwise you need to set the position for the `Process` column.

```cs
table.Columns["Process"]!.SetOrdinal(0);
```

Declare a BindingSource in the form

```cs
private BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
```

Assign the DataTable to the BindingSource DataSource then assign the BindingSource to the DataSource for the DataGridView.

Code to get checked rows

```cs
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> dataRows = ((DataTable)_bindingSource.DataSource).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<bool>("Process"));
```

Get the primary key, change `ProductId` to your primary key.

```cs
if (dataRows.Any())
{
    var keys = dataRows.Select(x => x.Field<int>("ProductId")).ToList();
}
```

The idea here is to work against the data rather than having to touch the DataGridView to get at any data including checked rows.