# Get value of checkbox in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I tried to get value of checked checkbox in DataGridView, so I check if value is true or false:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value == true)
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value = true;
                    }

                    button2.Enabled = (counter > 0);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It involks an error in line:

```
if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value == true)
```

Second solution:

```
 if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value == null || (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value == false)
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value = true;

                        counter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["check"].Value = false;

                        counter--;
                    }
```

The code below works, but sometimes checkbox is not checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify if a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell is Checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563190/how-to-verify-if-a-datagridviewcheckboxcell-is-checked)

Comment: You took the question code. Try the answers code :)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: What error message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something really similar in a project of mine, 
I am only using OnCellValueChanged instead of CellContentClick.

Here's my working line of code

```
bool completed = Convert.ToBoolean(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

What is exactly your error? Did you try to see what .Value was in the debugger ?

Comment: See my question again, I added new solution, but it checkes time after time

Comment: what do you mean by : but sometimes checkbox is not checked ?